# How do I print some text in matlab in plot?

Tags: matlab

In Matlab, I want to print as the following code at plot in Matlab.
the code lise this,

```
for i=1:100
print("%d",i);
end
```

How do I print some text in Matlab in plot?

Comment: Where do you want to print the text? Do you have fixed positions, do you want to label data in a plot? Please provide some more information (possibly with example image)

Comment: @hbaderts I wan to print at plot figure window. As you know, You can see the some figure window when you type 'plot' in command line. nothing special what  I want to do that.

Comment: Then I can only point to the answer of TalDarom.. This is the most universal way of printing text in a figure window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding [Tal Darom's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/987599/tal-darom) answer

**Vertical:**

```
figure; axis([0,20,0,60], 'image'); %image -> for 1:1 scale
for i=1:10
text(10, i*5, num2str(i)); %text can only print strings. so converting number to string
end
```

**Result:**

[image]

**Horizontal**

```
figure; axis([0,60,0,20], 'image'); %image -> for 1:1 scale
for i=1:10
text(i*5, 10, num2str(i)); %text can only print strings. so converting number to string
end
```

**Result:**

[image]

I think you can change the value and the position they are being printed by just tweaking the code

Answer (score 1):

Using the matlab `text` command. [link](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/text.html?refresh=true)

Comment: Is this only simple easy way?

Comment: @BONGKA I can't really understand what you are asking. If you will make an example image of what you want to achieve that can help.

Comment: Thanks, Sorry for late, I mean that 'text' is just printing some text. But I want to print some variable. oh. @Santhan Salai, already did it what i want to do.